# Website and Web Services Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, website, web-applications, alerts

I'm looking for a good product (either stand-alone or remote) that will monitor our online services. We're in a transition period between new asp.net and old foxpro / cgi and because of this experience errors that can make our services unresponsive.

Can anyone suggest internal/external tools, subscription based solutions, or anything else that I can put in place to monitor all aspects of our web services?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Circonus (http://circonus.com/) is perfect for this.  It's a SaaS service, so you don't have the headache of managing the monitoring software/hardware.  It does fault-detection, notifications and has awesome graphing features (including real-time graphs).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm going to have a look at their feature list right now.

Comment: I removed this comment because I placed it under the wrong comment.

Answer (score 1):

[nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is first thing that comes into my mind. with [tones of plugins](http://exchange.nagios.org/) you can monitor really a lot. depending on type of your service you might want to run nagios both externally [ just to check http responses - you can do it on some VPS ] and internally [ to monitor all the plumbing, databases, que sizes and whatever else you have up there ]. you can use some paid sms service to send alerts on your mobiles or if mails are enough - just send them.

there are also alternative open source solutions like [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/). i used nagios in setup with 80 servers and with over 1000 monitored services, but there are people that successfully run it at much smaller and bigger scales [ eg at [goldman](http://www.usenix.org/event/lisa07/tech/gaspar_talk.pdf) [sachs](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-2694482537942655203) ].

Comment: Does Nagios provide the ability to perform transactional testing? I really need a service to log in to our website, navigate our services, perform some various searches, and log back out. If it can do this then I would be very impressed. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @JohnyD nagios provides you each and every feature you can script. my take on it is to write testing logic in separate script run from cron, have this script log information to sql database and have nagios check freshness of that info and final result of a test.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for website monitoring Service. I recommend http://100pulse.com to monitoring your website. Because they provide instant alert through email, sms, rss feed, twitter, gadget. Also their summary reports helps our website or service's performance at all the time. I terms of cost they provide both free as well as paid...

Comment: After further review 100Pulse is not what I'm looking for. It lacks transactional tools. Thanks regardless.